# Windows explorer stop responding on laptop startup

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, windows-explorer

From few days ago, I am seeing windows explorer not working or not responding on my laptop startup. The whole desktop screen and also mouse cursor stop responding.

I have to wait for some time and then it automatically popups a dialog that asks to close or to restart windows explorer. After choosing any of these option everything behaves normally.

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue so that it will not arrive again in future.
I am using Windows7 OS 32 bit 4GB RAm, core-i3 processor on a laptop.

Comment: Does it happen in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135)?

Comment: Scan your system for malware or virus. It may be some worm consuming CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to startup programs or shell extensions that are not fully compatible with Explorer.

To see startup processes, press <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, type `msconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Go to **StartUp** tab and disable any software that you believe it may cause the problem.

To see shell extensions you'll need a software like **[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds)**. Go to **Tools**, **Startup** and **Context Menu**. If you go to **Windows** tab, you can disable startup applications from there just like in `msconfig`.

Comment: Thankyou Cornelius for your answer, it really helped me a lot!!